# Android. Доступ к самой примитивной графике

Tags: java, android, графика

Есть ли способ отрисовки примитивнее Canvas? Грубо говоря, мне надо перерисовывать каждый кадр по пикселям, а делать это при помощи Canvas дико медленно.

Comment: можно заполнить битмап как массив пикселей, а потом вывести его за раз.

Comment: Заполнение битмапа поп пикселям происходит медленно, максимум фпс 5 получалось выжать таким способом

Comment: Заполняйте через JNI